# Unable to load audio files using librosa

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa

`y, sr = librosa.load("random.wav",sr=22050)`

I am trying to load an audio file at a sampling rate of 22050 but I receive this error:

AttributeError: module 'cffi' has no attribute 'FFI'

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.0

Comment: 3.0? That is 12 years old, not really supported anymore. Update to Python 3.6 or newer, then try again

Comment: I have updated but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Did you reinstall all packages after the upgrade? Python packages with built files are specific to a Python minor version, generally

Comment: At least try to reinstall cffi

Comment: I tried reinstalling cffi as you said. Still getting the same error. I tried loading other files and it works fine. Is it possible that the issue is with the audio file?

Comment: Cffi probably only needed for some audio formats